# try to set image with has no effect

Tags: java, android, image, view, picasso

i'm trying to set height and width to my image view holder that contain pissico

so i'm trying several codes and it did not worked for me

not that i'm not using set conetntView because i'm using ScrollView as parent and created it dynamically

```
                 ImageView Photo = new ImageView(container.getContext());
                Photo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                Photo.requestLayout();
                Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(R.drawable.no_spic)
                        .error(R.drawable.no_internet)
                        .tag(container.getContext())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_spic)
                        .into(Photo);

                Step.addView(Photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **resize(width, height)**

Edit your code to

```
Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(R.drawable.no_spic)
                        .error(R.drawable.no_internet)
                        .tag(container.getContext())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_spic)
                        .into(Photo)
                        .resize(width,height);
```

Comment: how to set hight wrapconent?

Comment: Use **.resize(width, Photo.getHeight())**